# How to create a dynamic route to access a particular page in API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx, react-router-dom

I'm trying to build an ecommerce site product details page in React and React-Router-DOM v6. I have an API where I have some fields like `name`, `title`, `id`, and others.

I already created a product page which display cards, now I want to build the product description page where `useParams` is given to `id`, but when I implement the code it shows `undefined`.

If I put the `id` value manually in URL in the browser I got the results in console.

Code and screen shots attached.

The first time when URL load on product page, console is also given

[image]

The second image when I clicked on card

[image]

The third image when I entered the manual value in URL, like `"product/17"`

[image]

Products

```
import { Col, Container, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import Navbars from "../Components/Navbars";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
import "./Products.css";
import { ShoppingCart } from "lucide-react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function Products() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  const getProduct = async () => {
    try {
      const jwtToken = Cookies.get("jwt_token");

      const apiUrl = "https://apis.ccbp.in/products";

      const options = {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${jwtToken}`,
        },
        method: "GET",
      };

      const response = await fetch(apiUrl, options);
      const data = await response.json();

      setProducts(data.products);

      console.log(data);
      // console.log(data.products[16].id);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getProduct();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Navbars />

      <Container fluid>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <Link to={`/products/${products.id}`}>
              <div>
                <h2 className="mains-heading"> All Products</h2>
              </div>
              <div className="p3-5 prods">
                {products.map((item, index) => {
                  const { brand, image_url, price, rating, title } = item;

                  return (
                    <div key={index} className="product-container">
                      <img src={image_url} alt="" className="map-image" />
                      <div className="card-body">
                        <h5 className="card-title text-center pt-2">
                          {title.substr(0, 30)}
                        </h5>
                        <p className="card-text text-center">{`by ${brand}`}</p>

                        <p className="text-center price">{`₹ ${price}`}</p>

                        <p className="ratings text-center">{`⭐  ${rating}`}</p>
                        <div className="btns text-center">
                          <button className="btns">
                            Add to Cart{<ShoppingCart />}{" "}
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
              </div>
            </Link>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}

export default Products;
```

ProductsDetailedView

```
import Products from "./Products";
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

function ProductsDetailPage() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const params = useParams();
  const { id } = params;
  console.log(id);
  // console.log(params);

  const getProductDetails = async () => {
    try {
      const jwtToken = Cookies.get("jwt_token");

      const apiUrl = "https://apis.ccbp.in/products/" + `${id}`;

      const options = {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${jwtToken}`,
        },
        method: "GET",
      };

      const response = await fetch(apiUrl, options);
      const data = await response.json();
      setProducts(data.products);

      // setProducts(data.products);

      console.log(data);
      // console.log(data.products[16].id);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getProductDetails();
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <>
      this is dynamic route
      <h1> {id}</h1>
    </>
    //   <div>
    //    <Link to= "/products ${id}"> </Link>
    //   </div>
  );
}

export default ProductsDetailPage;
```

App.js

```
import "./App.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import Login from "./Components/Login";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Pages/Home";
import Page404 from "./Components/page404";
import Carts from "./Pages/Carts";
import Products from "./Pages/Products";
import Protected from "./Components/Protected";
import ProductsDetailPage from "./Pages/ProductsDetailPage";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Protected Comp={Home} />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/carts" element={<Protected Comp={Carts} />} />
          <Route path="/products" element={<Protected Comp={Products} />} />
          <Route path="/*" element={<Page404 />} />
          <Route path="/products/:id" element={<ProductsDetailPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`products` is the array of product data, so `products.id` is undefined.

Move the `Link` into the mapped callback so you can correctly link from each specific product by `product.id`

Example:

```
function Products() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  ...

  return (
    <>
      <Navbars />
      <Container fluid>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <div>
              <h2 className="mains-heading"> All Products</h2>
            </div>
            <div className="p3-5 prods">
              {products.map((product) => {
                const { brand, id, image_url, price, rating, title } = product;

                return (
                  {/* link to specific product id */}
                  <Link key={id} to={`/products/${id}`}>
                    <div className="product-container">
                      <img src={image_url} alt="" className="map-image" />
                      <div className="card-body">
                        <h5 className="card-title text-center pt-2">
                          {title.substr(0, 30)}
                        </h5>
                        <p className="card-text text-center">
                          by {brand}
                        </p>
                        <p className="text-center price">
                          ₹ {price}
                        </p>
                        <p className="ratings text-center">
                          ⭐  {rating}
                        </p>
                        <div className="btns text-center">
                          <button className="btns">
                            Add to Cart{<ShoppingCart />}
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </Link>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi Drew Thanks for your quick response. I did the same but still getting the same error it is showing undefined in console. please guide me further. Thank you.

Comment: @Saurabh Have you saved your edits and ensured the app is updated to your browser? It looks like all the products data has an `id` property. After moving the link into the map callback do you see the correct target URL path if you hover the link and upon clicking it do you see the URL in the address bar correctly update to the specific `"/products/X"` path?

Comment: No it it not showing the correct Url. its shows like products/undefined. But if I entered the value of id manually in URL, the desired data is fetched by API. I think it is not able to recognise the ID, Please check my API data again as I already Attached in Screenshot, Like If I console.log(products.id) it shows undefined but If I console.log(products[1].id) it shows the correct id.

Comment: @Saurabh Then I think your old code may still be running/served. Kill any running development servers/hot-reloaders/etc, ensure your latest changes are saved, and restart the app. What is the *exact* link `to` prop you are trying to use now?

Comment: I restarted everything. still having same issue. Actually in to prop I passed as a id with the help of useParam() hook but last 4 days I'm getting the same error. Is there any way that we can connect so you can access my machine and review my code if possible. As I tried everything at my own and lastly I asked here. Thank you.

Comment: @Saurabh Can you see if you can create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of this UI? Mock the `products` array data so you don't have to create a fetching logic. We just need to see how `products` is mapped to the tiles and the links and routes.

Comment: Sure, Actually this API uses Jwt_token ,so I need to build a replica over codesandbox ,just wait for me for few mins, I will share the link soon.

Comment: @Saurabh That's why I said to just provide the products data you have as a mock so the sandbox doesn't need to futz around with access tokens and we can get straight to the issue/problem of rendering links from the products data and navigating to another frontend route. Even just a products array sample with just 2 or 3 products would probably be sufficient. Does this make sense?

Comment: I'm Having difficulty to understand as I haven't used codesandbox much.can you please exaplain me bit more should I import my github repository (as This code is avaiable on my github too ) and add the dummy data ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256821/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-saurabh).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found out the solution actually In the link section I was giving path "/products/products.${id}" which is actually "/products/${id}". Now I'm able to redirect the page. But again thank you for your valuable quick response 